# check if date is within range, ignore the year

Tags: javascript

I want to check if a date is within a range but I want to ignore the year.

For example:

```
let data = [{dateFrom: '2021-03-01', dateTo: '2021-04-01', nextYear: false},
{dateFrom: '2021-12-01', dateTo: '2022-01-10', nextYear: true}]; // can't be changed

let today = new Date();

let todaysData = data.filter((x) => {
if(x.nextYear) {
  return new Date(x.dateFrom + ' 00:00:00') < today && new Date(x.dateTo + ' 23:59:59') > today
} else {
  return new Date(x.dateFrom + ' 00:00:00') < today && new Date(x.dateTo + ' 23:59:59') > today
}
});
```

The first data sample should be true if today is between March 1st and April 1st.
The second one if today is between December 1st and January 10th.

This works if the year is the same but I want it that regardless of the year, that this expression is true. Also if the range has the next year in it, the "nextYear" flag is set. (means like the range is every year from December to January)

How can I do that?

Comment: What is the difference between `if` and `else` blocks?

Comment: @ShivamSingla Nothing, I just tried something but found that it does not work. So I left the block there to show that there should be a difference when `nextYear` is set.

Comment: There are a variety of date libraries around  that have comparison methods you can use to do this easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having read the OP's acceptance criteria very carefully one approach was to write e.g. a `getYearLeveledTime` helper function which normalizes every date-format string-value into a date-time number-value. This date-time's full year base is leveled to 1970, regardless of the passed date-format. Only the month and the date of such a format are taken into account. An additional flag increases the time-value by the timed amount of a full year. And just in order to stay in any case at the save side, another tiny helper like `getSanitizedTimeRange` takes care of the correct range-value precedence.

Having set up the above it is much more easy to write a filter function which just needs to look whether a certain time-value is within a time-range. The task actually boils down to the return value of ... `(time >= timeFrom) && (time <= timeTo)`.

```js
function getSanitizedTimeRange(a, b) {
  return ((a < b) && [a, b]) || [b, a];
}
function getYearLeveledTime(date, isAddOneYear) {
  date = (date && new Date(date)) || new Date();
  const baseDate = new Date(0);

  baseDate.setDate(date.getDate());
  baseDate.setMonth(date.getMonth());

  if (isAddOneYear) {
    baseDate.setFullYear(baseDate.getFullYear() + 1);
  }
  return baseDate.getTime();
}

function isBoundTimeWithinYearAgnosticRange(dateItem) {
  const [
    timeFrom,
    timeTo,
  ] = getSanitizedTimeRange(
    getYearLeveledTime(dateItem.dateFrom),
    getYearLeveledTime(dateItem.dateTo, dateItem.nextYear)
  );
  const { time } = this; // bound time.

  // whether time is within range or not.
  return (time >= timeFrom) && (time <= timeTo);
}

const data = [
  {dateFrom: '2021-03-01', dateTo: '2021-04-01', nextYear: false},
  {dateFrom: '2021-12-01', dateTo: '2022-01-10', nextYear: true},
];

console.log(
  'filtered, year agnostic, time ranges ...',
  data.filter(isBoundTimeWithinYearAgnosticRange, { time: getYearLeveledTime() })
);

console.log(
  "today's base time ... new Date(getYearLeveledTime()) ...",
  new Date(getYearLeveledTime()),
  `(${ getYearLeveledTime() })`
);
console.log(
  'new Date(getYearLeveledTime("2021-12-01")) ...',
  new Date(getYearLeveledTime("2021-12-01")),
  `(${ getYearLeveledTime("2021-12-01") })`
);
console.log(
  'new Date(getYearLeveledTime("2022-01-10", true)) ...',
  new Date(getYearLeveledTime("2022-01-10", true)),
  `(${ getYearLeveledTime("2022-01-10", true) })`
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

what if you create a date to compare
kind of  put them in the same year

```
let today = new Date();
let dateToCompare = new Date(''+ today.getYear()+'-'+
x.dateFrom.getMounth()+'-'+ x.dateFrom.getDay());
```

I don't think it's the best option but could work

Comment: Could work, but doesn't work anymore if the range has differend years. Like in the second example.

Comment: you can do that in the if next year so it will be `today.getDate() + 1` if next year otherwise use `today.getDate()`

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the data by converting the `dateFrom` and `dateTo` values to ISO 8601 date strings and then passing them to the `Date` constructor. You do not even need to utilize the `nextYear` flag.

**Update** If you want to include dates that are `true` for `nextYear`, you can set their years to the current year and swap them if then `dateFrom` exceeds the `dateTo`.

```js
/**
 * Filters an array of data objects containing date ranges.<p>
 * @param {Object[]} data - an array of objects
 * @param {String} data.dateFrom - data start date
 * @param {String} data.dateTo - data end date
 * @param {Boolean} data.nextYear - if the {@code dateTo} goes into next year
 * @param {Date} [date=new Date()] - target date within data's date range
 * @return a filtered data array
 */
const filterData = (data, date = new Date()) =>
  data.filter(x =>
    ((startDate, endDate) => {
      if (x.nextYear) {
        startDate.setFullYear(date.getFullYear());
        endDate.setFullYear(date.getFullYear());
        if (startDate > endDate) {
          let tmp = startDate;
          startDate = endDate;
          endDate = tmp;
        }
      }
      return date >= startDate && date <= endDate;
    })
    (new Date(`${x.dateFrom}T00:00:00`), new Date(`${x.dateTo}T23:59:59`)))

const data = [
  { dateFrom: '2021-03-01', dateTo: '2021-04-01', nextYear: false },
  { dateFrom: '2021-12-01', dateTo: '2022-01-10', nextYear: true  }
];

console.log(filterData(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: That only works if the year is right, but I want to ignore the year. `dateFrom: '2022-03-01', dateTo: '2022-04-01'` or `dateFrom: '2020-03-01', dateTo: '2020-04-01'` should also be true today.

Comment: @sirzento I just updated the response, Hopefully it satisfies the condition.